# Inheritance in T4 template

Tags: c#, inheritance, t4

I have two .tt files (template1.tt & template2.tt) which has some part of the code to be same.

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="false" language="C#" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.IO" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Reflection" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>

<#
Assembly assem1 = Assembly.LoadFrom("a.dll");
Assembly assem2 = Assembly.LoadFrom("b.dll");

#>
```

The above is the common code within <#...#>

So I wanted to remove the common part from the T4 template.
I tried using the creating a base template (Template3).

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="false" language="C#" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Reflection" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ output extension=".txt" #>

<#+ 

    public void loadAssemblies()
    {
    Assembly assem1 = Assembly.LoadFrom("a.dll");
Assembly assem2 = Assembly.LoadFrom("b.dll");

    }

#>
```

Now when I am trying to add

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="false" language="C#" inherits="Template3" #>
```

the tt file is not compiling.

The error is

**Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Compiling transformation: The type or namespace name 'Template3' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   Template    C:\Users\xxx\source\repos\Template\Template\Template2.tt    1**

Any suggestions where I am wrong or how can I remove the duplicates ?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using *inheritance*, you should look into `.ttinclude` files as explained (its actually not very well explained... merely alluded to) in [Guidelines for All T4 Templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/guidelines-for-writing-t4-text-templates?view=vs-2019#guidelines-for-all-t4-templates). Your `.tt` file becomes the main orchestration and you call methods defined in the included files.

> Inheritance can work, but it becomes hard to manage long term, you'll find that using *include* files allow you to be more flexible, by keeping common sets of useful routines in different files, over time you will be able to use these files in a more diverse set of scenarios. Think of `.ttinclude` as being like [Header Files in C](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_header_files.htm#:%7E:text=C%20-%20Header%20Files%201%20Include%20Syntax.%20Both,3%20Once-Only%20Headers.%20...%204%20Computed%20Includes.%20) that bring the other files inline with the current file.

#### common.ttinclude

```
<#@ CleanupBehavior Processor="T4VSHost" CleanupAfterProcessingTemplate="true" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Reflection" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>

<#+ 

public static Assembly assem1 = null;
public static Assembly assem2 = null;
public static void loadAssemblies()
{
    assem1 = Assembly.LoadFrom("a.dll");
    assem2 = Assembly.LoadFrom("b.dll");
}

#>
```

#### template

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="false" language="C#" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.IO" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Reflection" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ include file="common.ttinclude"#>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>

<#
loadAssemblies();


#>
```